# How to deal with hyphens in .bib files?

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

I am using a .bib files for my references. Some entries have a hyphen in the title or in the abstract which mess up with LaTex. It returns

```
l.22 ...y Local Adaptation and Fitness Trade,Äė
                                                 Offs}
```

Here is the .bib entry

```
@article{Hereford2009,
author = {Hereford, Joe},
doi = {10.1086/597611},
file = {:Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/Literature/BackgroundSelection/597611.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0003-0147},
journal = {The American Naturalist},
keywords = {adaptation,genetic drift,genotype-by-environment interaction,local,natural selection,population divergence,reciprocal},
number = {5},
pages = {579--588},
title = {{A Quantitative Survey of Local Adaptation and Fitness Trade‐Offs}},
url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/597611},
volume = {173},
year = {2009}
}
```

How can I deal with it without having to replace them in the whole .bib file?

Here are my packages and document configuration

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
a4paper,
oneside,
%twoside,
headinclude,footinclude,
BCOR5mm, 
]{scrartcl}

\input{structure.tex}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}

\hyphenation{Fortran hy-phen-ation}
```

Comment: How was the bib entry created -- by typing all words at a keyboard, or by copying and pasting from some source? Are you sure these dashes are "simple" dashes, or could they be non-ASCII-encoded en-dash, em-dash, or math-minus signs?

Comment: The bib file was automatically produced by Mendeley. The symbol is short and is a hyphen if I am not mistaken (which I failed to notice before).

Comment: If the dash character in question were a simple, i.e., ASCII-encoded, character (decimal "45", hex "2D"), BibTeX and LaTeX would *not* be complaining. The only possibility left, then, is that the character -- even though it may 'look like' a dash -- is not ASCII-encoded; what it really is is anyone's guess at this point. Is there something keeping you from doing a global search-and-replace on the character?

Comment: No, I could just do search-and-replace but I thought that it was a good opportunity to learn about LaTex by finding "LaTex-way" around this problem. But well...if there are none, then I will just delete my post I guess!

Comment: It would help if you posted a couple of bib entries that contain offending dash-like characters.

Comment: Post edited! Thnks

Comment: Are you using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your document?

Comment: No, I'm not. I added some info on the packages used and document configuration in the post. Thanks

Comment: @Remi.b There should be a call to `inputenc` in `structure.tex`, probably.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dash character in the line

```
title = {{A Quantitative Survey of Local Adaptation and Fitness Trade‐Offs}},
```

is indeed not a "simple" dash (ASCII code 45), but a unicode-encoded character (code U+2010).

Observe that this is a LaTeX issue, not a BibTeX issue.

You can do several things. E.g.,

- Do a global search of `‐` (U+2010) and replace all instances with `-` (U+0045).
- Switch to a TeX engine and a font family that can handle the character `U+2010` directly. In the following example, LuaLaTeX and the EB Garamond font are used.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Hereford2009,
author  = {Hereford, Joe},
doi     = {10.1086/597611},
file    = {:Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/Literature/BackgroundSelection/597611.pdf:pdf},
issn    = {0003-0147},
journal = {The American Naturalist},
keywords= {adaptation,genetic drift,genotype-by-environment interaction,local,natural selection,population divergence,reciprocal},
number  = {5},
pages   = {579--588},
title   = {{A Quantitative Survey of Local Adaptation and Fitness Trade‐Offs}},
url     = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/597611},
volume  = {173},
year    = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % choose your bibliography style

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get a similar error, Unicode character U+2002 (inputenc) not set up for use with Latex. I have loaded `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Is there anything I am missing, because search and replace did not help. The dash seems to cause the error. The bibliography is created, but the title is wrong. Before the word containing the dash, a space is missing.

Comment: @ghx - Please note that my answer was geared specifically to LuaLaTeX, not pdfLaTeX. LuaLaTeX handles utf8-encoded characters natively, whereas pdfLaTeX does not. The character "U+2002" is an en-space. I suggest you track down all of its instances and replace each and every one of them with `--`.

Comment: Thanks @Mico I found the issue. It was an "en space" which I could not see w/o a specific editor.

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce the faulty output if I have `\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}` in my document.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Hereford2009,
author = {Hereford, Joe},
doi = {10.1086/597611},
file = {:Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/Literature/BackgroundSelection/597611.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0003-0147},
journal = {The American Naturalist},
keywords = {adaptation,genetic drift,genotype-by-environment interaction,local,natural selection,population divergence,reciprocal},
number = {5},
pages = {579--588},
title = {{A Quantitative Survey of Local Adaptation and Fitness Trade‐Offs}},
url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/597611},
volume = {173},
year = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\cite{Hereford2009}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change this to

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Hereford2009,
author = {Hereford, Joe},
doi = {10.1086/597611},
file = {:Users/remi/Documents/Biologie/Literature/BackgroundSelection/597611.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0003-0147},
journal = {The American Naturalist},
keywords = {adaptation,genetic drift,genotype-by-environment interaction,local,natural selection,population divergence,reciprocal},
number = {5},
pages = {579--588},
title = {{A Quantitative Survey of Local Adaptation and Fitness Trade‐Offs}},
url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/597611},
volume = {173},
year = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8,applemac]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2010}{-}

\begin{document}

\cite{Hereford2009}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\inputencoding{utf8}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\inputencoding{applemac} % just in case something follows

\end{document}
```

I get correct output.

[image]

It's best if you start using UTF-8 for all of your documents.